# Why does Powershell's "return" keyword cause type errors?

Tags: powershell

```
$xml = [xml] '<node>foo</node>'
function foo2 { return "foo2" }

# all of these fail with the message:
# **Cannot set "foo" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.**
$xml.node = foo2
$xml.node = foo2 -as [string]  # because of this issue[1]
$xml.node = (foo2)  

# these work
$xml.node = (foo2).tostring()
$xml.node = (foo2) -as [string]
$xml.node = [string] (foo2)

# yet, these two statements return the same value
(foo2).gettype()
(foo2).tostring().gettype()
```

1: [PowerShell functions return behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149191/powershell-functions-return-behavior)

Comment: Works for me, at least. No error messages here, neither in Powershell 1.0 on Vista, nor in Powershell 2.0 in Windows 7 RC.

Comment: Works for me too. Powershell 1 & 2 on XP.

Comment: I came across the script where I'd put in this workaround, and took the opportunity to figure out what caused the error.  It's the "return" statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got some confirmation from the PowerShell team on this one.  This appears to be a bug in the XML adapter.  If you look at the object that is spit out by foo2 in a debugger it is a PSObject.  If you don't use the return keyword and instead just output the string "foo2" then the function returns a string object.

The bug in the XML adapter is that it is not unwrapping the PSObject to get at the base object.  As a result when it tries to assign the PSObject to $xml.node it fails.  For now, as a workaround, you can manually unwrap the psobject like so (or just cast to [string]):

```
$xml = [xml] '<node>foo</node>'
function foo2 { return "foo2" }
$xml.node = (foo2).psobject.baseobject
$xml

node
----
foo2
```

Comment: Way to work the MVP connections, Keith :)  Unfortunately it won't let me change my designated answer, but here's a +1 for ya.

Comment: If I delete my answer will it let you reassign?

Comment: Ah no - I cannot delete an accepted answer, sorry. hopefully the note to look at this one will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, functions may return an array (of length 1) where your expected result is at index 0 in the array. To ensure you always get a scalar if a single element is returned wrapped in an array, use the following syntax:

```
$xml.node = $( myfunc )
```

Hope this helps,

-Oisin

p.s. I know others cannot repro this, and nor can I, but I suspect your demo code is cut out from some other, larger script.

Comment: It could also be true that the function is not returning strings, but something else that easily displays via PowerShell's output formating.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!811.entry) I would assume that the compiler decides it doesn't know the output type of foo2 well enough to accept it despite it being 'obvious' that it will always be a string I assume there is some code route capable of adding something more to the output that is never exercised...

Update: Keith Hill's answer is the correct one not this one

Comment: Based on other things I've seen from Powershell (and scripting languages in general), I assumed it would execute the function and examine its return value dynamically.  But until I hear otherwise definitively, your answer sounds like the most likely reason.

Comment: Oooh you pushed me over the top to 10K tah :)