# Why does Get-Date seem to return DateTime objects, but the BinarySerializer indicate it returns a PSObject?

Tags: datetime, powershell, binary-serialization, psobject

Take the simple [HashTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx):

```
$data = @{
    First = 'Justin';
    Last = 'Dearing';
    StartDate = Get-Date '2002-03-23';
}
```

The key StartDate seems to contain a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime).

```
C:\Users\zippy\Documents> $data.StartDate.GetType().FullName
System.DateTime
```

However, if I attempt to perform binary serialization on it, I get an exception complaining that [PSObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not serializable.

```
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $data)
$ms.Close()
```

Throws:

```
DocumentsException calling "Serialize" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' in Assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Versio
n=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable."
At C:\Users\jdearing\AppData\Local\Temp\b8967f99-0a24-41f7-9c97-dad2bc288bd9.ps1:12 char:14
+ $bf.Serialize <<<< ($ms, $data)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

This message goes away and everything works if I use an explicit cast to [DateTime] like so:

```
$data = @{
    First = 'Justin';
    Last = 'Dearing';
    StartDate = [DateTime] (Get-Date '2002-03-23');
}
```

So is Get-Date not really returning a DateTime, or is some other powershell oddity at work here.

Comment: I think everything in PS defaults to `PSObject` unless you explicitly define the type.  It does dynamic datatype conversions, so it could just be returning a string that it interprets as a `System.Datetime` at runtime.

Comment: @JNK but why Object.GetType() interpret something as a DateTime that the binary formatter interprets as PSObject?

Comment: This is just guessing, but maybe because it's being interpreted at runtime (since you are running the `GetType()` method of a PSObject) - the binary formatter is a system class, not a PS class

Comment: ( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [psobject] True -- ( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [datetime] True -- [datetime]( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [datetime] True -- [datetime]( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [psobject] False

Comment: @Christian I think that's an answer,  post it and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Christian you should make that an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object in PowerShell is actually wrapped mostly transparently in a [PSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject). I say mostly transparently, because there are more than a few bugs in PowerShell that omit to remove the wrapper before leaking the object to another API. This causes all sorts of issues, much like the one you see now. Search connect.microsoft.com/powershell for PSObject wrapper. I believe this is no longer an issue in v3 with the new [DLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime)-based engine.

Comment: Just fired up VirtualBox and the code does work. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: here's another example where psobject screws things up; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837095/why-does-powershells-return-keyword-cause-type-errors

Answer (score 5):

Based on [MSDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network):

PSOobject Class:

Encapsulates a base object of type Object or type PSCustomObject to allow for a consistent view of any object within the Windows PowerShell environment.

```
( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [psobject]
True

( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [datetime]
True

[datetime]( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [datetime]
True

[datetime]( get-Date '2002-03-23' ) -IS [psobject]
False
```